# Scala generics function call

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following trait in scala:

```
trait BaseDao {

 type T <: BaseModel

 def saveModel(model: T)

}
```

I created a class which extends BaseDao:

```
 class Sample (dynamoDBMapper: DynamoDBMapper) extends BaseDao with LazyLogging {
 checkNotNull(dynamoDBMapper)

 protected def classType: Class[T] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]

 override def saveModel(model: T): Unit ={
   model.validate()

   dynamoDBMapper.save(model)
 }
```

Now, when I create the instance of above class and try to call save method:

```
    val testModel = new TestModel();
    testModel.setHashKey("a")
    testModel.setSortKey("b")
    testModel.setCreatedOn(new Date())
    testModel.setModifiedOn(new Date())

    sample.saveModel(testModel)
```

It gives the following error:

```
Type mismatch expected: Sample#T, actual: TestModel model class extends BaseModel class
```

I am new in scala and I am not able to figure out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined type `T` in `Sample`.

Rewrite your `Sample` class to look somewhat like this:

```
class Sample (dynamoDBMapper: DynamoDBMapper) extends BaseDao with LazyLogging {

  checkNotNull(dynamoDBMapper)

  type T = TestModel

  override def saveModel(model: T): Unit ={
   model.validate()

   dynamoDBMapper.save(model)
  }
}
```